# How do i hide a control in a report based on a field value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a checkbox control that i need to hide if a Boolean value is false. I have tried using the Detail_Format event to no avail. i put the field value into another checkbox, then tried setting the visible property from the value in the checkbox, no dice. In the image below, the rightmost checkbox is showing the value of the field that determines if the checkbox to the left of it should be shown. I have the following code

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
  If Me.chkRequireverify = True Then
  Me.chkVerified.Visible = True
  Else
  Me.chkVerified.Visible = False
  End If
  'Me.chkVerified.Visible = Me.chkRequireverify
End Sub
```

when i tried using the Detail_Paint event, it errored out telling me that i cant change the visible property in this event.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks to be correct and could be shortened to simply:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.chkVerified.Visible = Me.chkRequireverify
End Sub
```

However, I believe the event handler for the `OnFormat` event will only be evaluated when viewing the report in **Print Preview** view, rather than in **Report** view.

Whilst the `OnPaint` event fires in **Report** view, you cannot modify certain properties after the report has been formatted, the `Visible` property being one such property, along with the `Height` & `Width` properties (and so you also cannot shrink the checkboxes to zero size).

Comment: I originally used the format you did, I was just making sure that I wasn't doing a dumb mistake. It looks like the format event only triggers in print preview which... sucks. I utilize the report as a data browse, and have it set up so the users can double click a record for a drill down.

Comment: @KySoto I've updated my answer to provide more information.

Comment: Based on your information, I'm stuck. I'll throw you best answer even though its not what I wanted to hear.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used Access and VBA, but I believe what you're missing is `.Value` after the checkbox name in the `if` clause.

Try this : `If Me.chkRequireverify.Value = True`

Comment: The value property is the default member, BUT I did in fact try this, I just didn’t mention it because it didn’t seem pertinent. Thanks anyways

Comment: Ok, as I said I wasn't sure, I work typically in C#/XAML, and I know there it's required to add it.

Comment: UI design is my favorite aspect of coding, I'll take a look at it and see what I can help with.